# Get data from AlertDialog "itself"

Tags: kotlin, dialog, fragment

I'm currently trying to open an AlertDialog where some data will be displayed inside it.

```
class AlertsDialogRemi : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.alerts_dialog, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val alerts = arrayOf("AlertsDialogRemi 1", "AlertsDialogRemi 2", "AlertsDialogRemi 3")
    for(alert in alerts){
        Log.i(TAG, "Alert : $alert")
    }}
```

And I call it from this (MainActivity):

```
fun showDialog(){
    mydialog = Dialog(this, R.style.DialogCustomTheme)

    mydialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    mydialog.setContentView(R.layout.alerts_dialog_remi)

    mydialog.create()

    txt = mydialog.findViewById(R.id.close_modal_alerte)
    txt.isEnabled = true
    txt.setOnClickListener{
        mydialog.cancel()
    }
    mydialog.show()
}
```

When I open the fragment as a real fragment, I can my alerts. But when I open it as a Dialog, I don't see the alerts (but I have the layout displayed)

How can I get my alerts inside my AlertDialog (as a Dialog thanks to showDialog())?

Comment: For getting dialog you can use DialogFragment instead of Fragment. See details https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dialog has nothing to do with the `AlertsDialogRemi` class.  
Declare the `setOnShowListener` for the dialog, before `mydialog.show()`, and put the code you want to execute when the dialog is shown inside the lambda:

```
mydialog.setOnShowListener {
    //write your code here
}
```

> **setOnShowListener** 
>   public void setOnShowListener(DialogInterface.OnShowListener listener)
>  
>   Sets a listener invoked when the dialog is shown.

Comment: Ok. I should use an inflater and put content thanks to findViewById ?

Comment: If you want that same layout.

Comment: I did use **setOnShowListener**, but I didn't use my Alert class. I've filled the Dialog directly in the setOnShowListener. Thanks